# Deleting an object referenced from another agregate

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

An example taken from Applying DDD and Patterns book by Jimmy Nilsson:
[image: Order Aggregate and Product Entity]

Let's say i want to delete a **Product** that is referenced by some **OrderLine**, by delete i mean from the database, Why ?
Maybe because the system has been running for a long time and the user want's to clean up some old **Products**, how to solve this ?
Another question for those may have read the book, why did the author chose not to take a snapshot of the **Product** as he did for the **Customer** entity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since an order is effectively an immutable event, deleting a product from the database should not affect existing orders for that product. It is usually a good idea to copy applicable product data directly into the order line item - this may be what was referred to as the "snapshot" in Jimmy's book, but I'm not sure. Also, if you're using a relational database and you have a foreign key constraint on the product ID then you should either avoid deleting products or remove the constraint.

Comment: Sorry for the the incomplete\inaccurate question, the main problem doesn't lie in the deletion process itself, i know about foreign key constraints. The problem is in the Presentation, if a product was actually deleted and a customer was looking at his old orders, where is system going to get details about the products he purchased in one of those orders, so the most important question is actually the second one, why didn't he chose to copy product data to the order line item, please comment on this and the view problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure why he didn't do it, it may have been for explanatory purposes - to show the different ways to implement relationships. In your scenario, I think you should copy all applicable data to the order line so that it can be accessed for presentation purposes. This has benefits regardless of whether products are ever fully deleted.

Comment: I agree with eulerfx here: another issue may be pricing.  This too changes over time so the same historical product that you want to delete may very well have a different price over time.  The reason the price is not an issue is because it has been denormalized into the `OrderLine` since, typically, prices are maintained in supplier price lists.  So the easiest is to remove the high 'coupling' on the data level also.